# company branding doesn't work for password page in Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, branding

I've created company branding from the Azure portal for my application.

This is working as expected for the first page i.e, the username page. When I click on next for the password page, the custom branding disappears and default Microsoft background appears.

I want the branding to be continued for the password page also so that there would be consistency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably try to sign in with a **Microsoft Account** instead of your Azure Active Directory account. If you sign in with a "native" Azure Active Directory account you will continue see your company branded page.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I ve licked my gmail account(microsoft account) and I've tried. It doesn't work. How do I convert it to "native" Azure Active Directory account?? Thanks in advance..

Comment: if you have a microsoft (e. g. using gmail) account, AAD will redirect you to the microsoft login page, you cant avoid it (and you shouldn't since the user expects that). To see if your company branding work you can create a new AAD user and try to login with that user account

Comment: Yes it worked. There's another problem. I've given a logo in the portal. I want that particular logo to appear in the password screen also but now whatever domain the user logs in with that's coming by default. For example, I log in with facebook.com domain, facebook's icon is appearing but the background is as expected. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer and start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your Azure AD sign-in pages, which appear when users sign in to your organization's tenant-specific apps, such as https://outlook.com/contoso.com, or when passing a domain variable, such as https://passwordreset.microsoftonline.com/?whr=contoso.com.

Your custom branding won't immediately appear when your users go to sites such as, www.office.com. Instead, the user has to sign-in before your customized branding appears.

Visit this link for more information

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/customize-branding

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I've done exactly what's suggested in the link mentioned above. It doesn't work. When I enter the login page my custom brand appears. But it asks me to click "next" button to enter password. When I do that, it redirects to microsoft portal and gets the default page settings. So both the username and password pages have different themes which isn't my requirement. Is there a way to show username and password in the same screen?? Thanks in advance.