# How to perform Azure AD authentication without showing the microsoft login page?

Tags: reactjs, azure, authentication, azure-ad-msal

I need some clarification on the implementation of Azure AD authentication. The thing is I have a react js application in which I have implemented Azure AD authentication on a button click which is working fine and the current functionality is, on that button click a popup/redirect happens(just like an ss attached below) on the microsoft page where it asks for username and password and on submit it gets authenticated.

[image]

Now my expectation is I want to implement a flow in which I have a custom login page (just like an ss attached below) with two fields username and password. When I enter the username and password in the appropriate field and click on submit a request goes to microsoft Azure AD authentication and it provides me the response without showing the microsoft login page.

In short I want to skip the microsoft login page and want to perform the Azure AD authentication through my custom login screen and after successful login a microsoft popup may appear for further 2 factor authentication process.

[image]

So how this whole thing can be achieved in react application?
Please explain in detail with some code sample if possible.

Comment: With Entra ID you can personalize Branding, i guess what you are seeing bellow is a customized B2C login based on custom policies. With B2C you can send to a client app customizable rendering though /authorize with your custom CSS, Jquery ...

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the answer you are hoping for, but I would ask though is there a valid need for it to be a custom page? The reason I ask is because users should be trained in trusting Microsoft's (or any other IdP's) own login page, so you might be creating a bad practice, especially if this is for regular user logins. Why worry about safely passing the details to the IdP (which is general bad practice) when the user can and should be entering it directly with the IdP. Unless I am misunderstanding the use case. I understand breaking off from your app flow may be cause for concern, but if you are asking the user to login at the right moment in the app experience, they shouldn't be concerned with this minor 'inconvenience' of having a pop-up to login.

As mentioned in the comments, you can consider using Microsoft Graph with Microsoft Entra company branding. You would need one of these licenses though: Microsoft Entra ID P1 or P2, Microsoft Entra ID P1 or P2, Office 365 (for Office apps). Also note if your users or guests authenticate using a personal Microsoft account, the sign-in page doesn't reflect the branding of your organization I don't think.

More details can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/fundamentals/how-to-customize-branding

Comment: Thanks for your reply. With the help of your suggested approach I am able to do the branding on the login page of microsoft ans it's looking fine but when I enter the username and click on next the branding gets removed on the password page. What can be the possible reason for this?

Comment: what kind of account is being used to sign in?  to see the company branding the user needs to be an AAD user it seems, so if they are trying to sign in with a standard Microsoft account (personal) I think by design it will go to Microsoft page and not your custom one:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52399205/6696446

Comment: @AvanishSrivastava were you able to solve your issue?